# Why is my total time formula producing an incorrect result?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a column of five rows with total hours worked per day, and a sixth row with the formula adding rows 1-5.

[image: Here is what I'm seeing so far.]

The formula for total hours worked in a day is `=IF(C2<B2,C2+1,C2)-B2`, which produces the result I'm expecting per day.

- Cells B2:B3 (and subsequent) are formatted as `Time -> 1:30 PM`
- Cell D2 (and subsequent) is formatted as `Time -> 13:30`
- Cell D7 is formatted a `Time -> 13:30`

D7's formula is `SUM(D2:D6)`, but it ends up being 16 hours instead of the 40 I'm expecting. What am I doing incorrectly here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you format the cells only `hh:mm` then it will only show the hour portion of the total.

`40:00` would show as `16:00` because there is a full day and 16 hours.

to include all the hours one would need to use `[]`:

```
[hh]:mm
```

This will now show

```
40:00
```

[image]

Comment: i hate excel . Had this issue for weeks. Nice answer